# Vendor reliability and Privacy reputation

Tags: seo, optimization, statistics

When observing my website stats at [StatShow](http://www.statshow.com), I can see my *internet reputation* for:

> Trustworthiness
>
> Vendor reliability
>
> Privacy
>
> Child Safety

My site had excellent results for everything beside *Vendor reliability* (50 points) and *Privacy* (72 points). I am trying to decode what this means and what algorithm they use to determine these figures.

My question is, in terms of SEO, how do I improve points for Privacy and Vendor reliability? What is Vendor reliability anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SiteShow appears to be using the WOT service to find the Internet Reputation of a site. Over at the WOT website, they explain [what these terms mean](http://www.mywot.com/en/faq/add-on/new-to-wot#rating-criteria) -

> Trustworthiness reflects the overall trustworthiness of a website: Do
>   you consider this site safe to use? Does this site deliver you what it
>   promises? Do you trust the content of the website? A poor rating may
>   indicate Internet scams, identity theft risks, credit card fraud,
>   phishing, viruses, adware or spyware. The site may contain annoying
>   advertisements, excessive pop-ups or content that makes your browser
>   crash. A poor rating may also indicate that the site's content is not
>   trustworthy.
>
> Vendor Reliability tells you whether the site is safe for buying and
>   selling or for business transactions in general. An “excellent” rating
>   indicates superior customer service, timely delivery of products or
>   services and overall customer satisfaction. A "poor" rating indicates
>   possible fraud or a bad shopping experience.
>
> Privacy tells you whether the site has a privacy policy that protects
>   your personal identity and data. For example, does the social
>   networking service you use give you the means to determine what is
>   public and what remains private? Does the site have opt-in privacy
>   options? A "poor" rating indicates concern that your data may be sold
>   to 3rd parties, be stored indefinitely or be turned over to law
>   enforcement without a warrant, etc.
>
> Child safety indicates if the site contains age-inappropriate
>   material. This includes mature content meant for adults: Content
>   depicting nudity, sexual content, violence, vulgar or hateful language
>   or content that encourages dangerous or illegal activities.

I wonder if the above factors can really be measured and the results of the reputation service can be totally relied upon.

Here is a [snapshot of StatShow's rating of itself](http://www.statshow.com/www/statshow.com) -
[image]

Comment: So the Privacy is probably determined by the content of the Privacy Policy text, but how do they determine Vendor Reliability? Maybe it scans for links with costumer service/customer chat etc? I can't think of any other option. Nonetheless, thank you for posting their own reputation, that made my day.